# Using Highcharts with Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a Rails 6 app in which I am using Highcharts. I'm using plain JavaScript at the moment, then I'll transition to the highchart gem when I have the chart exactly how I want it. I have the chart almost exactly how I want it to render except for two things:

1. How can I use two different colors for a scatter chart?
2. How can I have just two lines bisecting my chart?

My data, at the moment is just a hard-coded array of arrays, something like this: `[[3, 5], [7, 3], [22, 10], [35, 35], [10, 5], [10, 7]]`. I would like to split the array in two and use two different colors for the points on the scatter chart.

For the lines, I would only like to show a line on the 'y' axis at point 50 (my y axis goes from 0 to 100) and one line on the 'x' axis at point 100 (my x axis goes from 0 to 200). Currently, I have both the lines on point 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split your data into two series and set individual color for them.
2. Set `gridLineWidth` to `0` for both axes and add the lines by `plotLines`.

---

```
chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    plotLines: [{
        value: 50
    }]
},
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    plotLines: [{
        value: 100
    }]
},
series: [{
    color: 'red',
    data: [
        [3, 5],
        [7, 3],
        [22, 10]
    ]
}, {
    color: 'blue',
    data: [
        [35, 35],
        [10, 5],
        [10, 7]
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vm9Lrgds/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines

Comment: Hi @hashrocket, Set `lineWidth` and `tickWidth` to `0`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tv756r9k/

Comment: That worked great. Sorry, one more question: Is there a way to set the opacity from 0 to 200 on the 'x' axis? For example, the dots closest to the 0 (on the 'x' axis) would be less opaque and then the dots would become more opaque as they get closer to 200.

Comment: Hi @hashrocket, Yes, you can use `colorAxis`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6fmqzhgo/

Comment: That partially worked, but it is changing the opaqueness from bottom to top instead of from left to right. How can I make it change the opaqueness from left to right?

Comment: Ah, sorry - you should additionally set `colorKey: 'x'` on a series level: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/60ysk5gm/

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know Ruby, I can help you only with JS.

Comment: @hashrocket, Could you create another SO question with `highcharts` tag and what you already have?